# How to get all the ID of all checked checkbox inside a Jquery bootgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The entire code works and the bootgrid is populated by data's. I have 2 rows inside the bootgrid and when I click the checkbox, it alerts the ID.
   [image]

If I put a check on the other checkbox, it also pop up the id.
My problem is, how can I get all the ID if I check the check all box (TITLE)?

[image]

Once I click the check all box, it alerts an ID, but only the last one, which is the Admin. How can I get all the ID of all checked box?
Here is my code.

```
var table = $('#user-list');

table.bootgrid({
    css     : {
        icon        : 'zmdi icon',
        iconColumns : 'zmdi-view-list',
        iconDown    : 'zmdi-caret-down',
        iconRefresh : 'zmdi-refresh',
        iconUp      : 'zmdi-caret-up',
    },
    labels  : {
        noResults   : noResult,
        loading     : loadingTable,
    },
    ajax         : true,
    url          : '/users/list',
    selection    : true,
    rowCount     : [10, -1],
    multiSelect  : true,
    navigation   : 2,
}).on("selected.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function(e, rows)
{
    alert("Selected: " + rows[0].id);
});
```

Comment: I 'm guessing you want them all to be checked when you click the check all button rather than just getting their ID's. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think you already have them in the `rows` array**.

So instead of `alert("Selected: " + rows[0].id);`, you can do the following:

If you want to get them as a string, separated by comma, for example, you can do:

```
var result = rows.map(function(row) { return row.id }).join(',');
```

If you want to get them as an `array`, you can do just:

```
var result = rows.map(function(row) { return row.id })
```

---

**If you use ES6, this can be more elegant**:

```
let result = rows.map(row => row.id).join(',');
```

and

```
let result = rows.map(row => row.id);
```

Comment: Hi @Dan, what if I check the checkbox one by one?  If I check the second checkbox, it should contain 2 id. If I check another checkbox, it will contain 3 ID. How can I do it?

Comment: I think it's already done. `rows` contains all selected checkboxes. You do not need to check them one by one.

Comment: Your solution is perfect, I'm just thinking what if I checked the checkbox one by one. Every time a new checkbox is selected the id will be shown + the previous id.